# Web API DbGeography Hangs Forever

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, spatial

I have an entity- **GeoEntity**- that has a `DbGeography` property. In my Web Api, I have a POST endpoint that allows you to add new **GeoEntities**.

Entity-

```
public class GeoEntity {

  [JsonProperty("point")]
  [NotMapped]
  public GeoPoint Point { get; set; }

  [JsonIgnore]
  public DbGeography Location {

    get 
    {
      // Breakpoint A
      return DbGeography.FromText($"POINT({Point.Longitude} {Point.Latitude})", 4326); 
    }

    set 
    {
      Point.Latitutde = value.Latitide;
      Point.Longitude = value.Longitude;
    }

  }

}

public class GeoPoint {

  public double Latitude { get; set; }

  public double Longitude { get; set; }

}
```

API -

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Add(GeoEntity entity)
{
  // Breakpoint B
  var newGeo = _geoService.Add(entity);
  return Ok(newGeo);
}
```

When I send the following post body-

```
{
  "point": {
    "latitude": 10,
    "longitude": 10
  }
}
```

I get stuck on **Breakpoint A**. When I continue from that endpoint, I never arrive at **Breakpoint B** and the http request is stuck *Pending* forever.

If I try stepping over, nothing happens.

I've captured the `FromText` result to a temporary `var x` to make sure it wasn't getting stuck trying to parse- and sure enough- it is not getting stuck trying to parse. The DbGeography object is created just fine.

If I return null in that get: `get { return null; }` I do arrive at **Breakpoint B**. But obviously my data is lost.

Any ideas why returning an actual `DbGeography` object causes the request to hang forever while returning `null` does not?

Comment: The example code is incomplete. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Serializer trouble

Based on your question, the `Breakpoint A` should never even get hit in the first place, because you are explicitly telling your serializer to ignore it, where it is obviously not doing so.

> It is very likely to be your serializer trying to serialize the property `Location` of type `DbGeography`.

Simply, **your serializer is not *ignoring* it** and trying to retrive the value to serialize it. Which is not your intent based on the decorator you have provided.

*Note:*
Depending on your serializer, you make need to use one of the following attributes/decorators

```
 // using System.Web.Extensions;
 // using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

 [IgnoreDataMember]                  
 [ScriptIgnore]                      
 [JsonIgnore]
 public DbGeography Location { ... }
```

Alternative is to use `DataContract` and `DataMember`

```
[DataContract]
public class Computer
{
    // included in JSON
    [DataMember]
    public GeoPoint Point { get; set; }

    // ignored
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
}
```

---

If for whatever reason you **are** trying to serialize it... Then you will need to verify that the implementation of `DbGeography.FromText()` and it's return type (`DbGeography`) is object is actually "serialize-able".